# MarkLogic updating locked document

Tags: marklogic

In Marklogic I have document locked using "xdmp:lock-acquire" by a user A. Is there any way (any permission/privilege) user B can be assigned so that user B can update document?

Thanks,
Shashi

Comment: Explain what kind of lock you are talking about. Add some more details in order to empower people to help you. Code sample, permissions sample, what exact features are you using?  I ask this because your (very vague) question could be talking about locks or permissions. Lastly, if you are using MarkLogic using admin, I suggest that you stop - and use another user. The admin user does not just have special privileges.. It also circumvents some security checks. It's a bad hole to dig yourself out of if you start developing that way.

Comment: I mean document is locked by calling xdmp:lock-for-update by user A. Now we want user B to be able to update this or add one more collection to this document. By default User B can't work on a document which user A has locked. But can any special privilege be assigned to user B with which user B can update document locked by A.

Comment: People will not read the comments in detail.. update your ticket itself to be clear and complete. Also, eplain the reason for using xdmp:lock-for-update. These locks are queued and are not what  likely what you think. There are other locks related to webDav features that may be more what you want (or not). Clear, complete questions(not comments) get better response from the community.